# How to Retrieve all the recursive parent of child row in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a hierarchical data of Category-Products. This is 3 level hierarchy & all the products will always be assigned to the last level. I want do display a drill down report of all the products grouped by Category - Sub Category & Sub Sub Category. Only those categories will be displayed on report for which we have product result. (Result Products are decided by some other criteria, out of scope for this question).

How can I get all the Category data till root level in oracle.

Sample Data

```
 CategoryId   Name           Parent
    1            Clothing       NULL
    2            Men's Wear     1
    3            Shirt          2
    4            T-Shirt        2
    5            Women's Wear   1
    6            Salwar         5
    7            Saree          5
    8            Electronics    NULL
    9            Computers      8
    10           Mobiles        8
```

Products table will have Category Id reference. Ex. 3, 4 or 6, 7 etc
I want to retrieve only categories till root level where we have products. I have below query but I am not sure if this is good practice to specify multiple values for `START WITH` clause. Is there any better option?

```
SELECT DISTINCT CategoryId,Name,Parent
FROM   tblCategory
START WITH CategoryId IN (3,6)
CONNECT BY CategoryId = PRIOR Parent
```

For above query I have specified only two categories but in real world it could be thousands. Below is result data showing only categories for selected products.

Output:

```
 CategoryId  Name          Parent
    1        Clothing      NULL
    2        Men's Wear    1
    3        Shirt         2
    5        Women's Wear  1
    6        Salwar        5
```

Comment: Please could you edit your question to include the output you'd like to see, based on your sample input data.

Comment: @Boneist Basically input is category Ids to which products are assigned.As it is mentioned 3, 4 , 6 & 7 & i have already included output at the end

Comment: Please update your question to include the output you'd like to see **as text**. Not all of us can see pictures, due to firewall restrictions.

Comment: @Boneist please check now

Comment: Is there a typo in your input data? Should Shirt have a parent of 2, not 3?

Comment: Yes, it should be Shirt & T-Shirt would have Parent 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically solved your problem. You can list ID's as you did or you can store them somewhere and use in `IN` subquery, like here for instance:

```
with tblCategory(CategoryId, Name, Parent) as (
    select  1, 'Clothing',      null from dual union all
    select  2, 'Men''s Wear',   1    from dual union all
    select  3, 'Shirt',         2    from dual union all
    select  4, 'T-Shirt',       3    from dual union all
    select  5, 'Women''s Wear', 1    from dual union all
    select  6, 'Salwar',        5    from dual union all
    select  7, 'Saree',         5    from dual union all
    select  8, 'Electronics',   null from dual union all
    select  9, 'Computers',     8    from dual union all
    select 10, 'Mobiles',       8    from dual ),
  ids(cid) as (select 3 from dual union all select 6 from dual)
select distinct categoryid, name, parent
  from tblcategory
  start with categoryid in (select cid from ids)
  connect by categoryid = prior parent
```

Result:

```
CATEGORYID NAME             PARENT
---------- ------------ ----------
         6 Salwar                5
         3 Shirt                 2
         5 Women's Wear          1
         2 Men's Wear            1
         1 Clothing
```

You could also produce more readable output like here:

```
select connect_by_root(categoryid) root, 
       sys_connect_by_path(name, ' => ') path
  from tblcategory
  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  start with categoryid in (select cid from ids)
  connect by categoryid = prior parent
```

Result:

```
  ROOT PATH
------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     3  => Shirt => Men's Wear => Clothing
     6  => Salwar => Women's Wear => Clothing
```

Comment: Is there a way we could bring only second level category, (Men's Wear & Women's Wear) only in Path column

Comment: Yes, like in this [example](https://rextester.com/XVCG5629), add `where level = 2` and remove condition for leaves. If you need only second level category just use column `name`, no need for `connect_by_path`.